# Choose program to send email

Tags: android, email

I have this code for send email:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{MyApp.sInstance.ErrorsMail});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.Proposal));
//intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.SendEmail)));
```

Unfortunately it shows me not only email applications:
Skype,FTP,GoogleDrive,GMail

How to limit list to email clients?

### UPDATE:

Adding

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
```

I receive: "No application can perform this action".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in your Intent..

**ACTION_SEND** is a generic Intent action that can be supported by any application that wants to. All you do is indicate what data you are sharing and the MIME type of that data -- from there, it is up to the user to choose from available activities.

The only way is some hack for use `Explicit Intent` with actual know of **PackageName** for the `Email Application`, and what type of `ACTION` it responses.

Comment: I am not sure about email apps instaled on device.How to call then?

Comment: Using Intent and Package Manager you can find, but also for intent you need which type of Action it responds.. It can be any app like, Social Media, Email...